# How can I know if a NSComboBox has currently the drop down list open?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I know if an NSComboBox currently has the dropdown list open or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `NSComboBoxDelegate` protocol is for.

Especially the methods `comboBoxWillPopUp:` and `comboBoxWillDismiss:` should give you the information you are looking for.

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSComboBoxDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSComboBoxDelegate/comboBoxWillPopUp%3a).

Answer (score 0):

One more way you can just connect the action method to combox box as well .So that whenever you click on the combox action method will get called